# Folland's proof of the Schwarz Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

It is probably obvious but I cannot figure out why the highlighted part is true:

[image: I did not figure out why]

> My attempt:
>
> When $\langle x,y\rangle =0$, "$\leq$" always hold. For equality, since $\langle x,y\rangle=0$, want to show $\|x\| \|y\|=0$ iff. $x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent.
>
> "$\Rightarrow$": 
> $\|x\| \|y\|=0$ iff $\|x\|=0$ or $\|y\|=0$ iff. $x=0$ or $y=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent
>
> "$\Leftarrow$": 
> $x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent iff $x=\alpha y$ or $y=\alpha x$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\|x\|\|y\|=|\alpha|\|x\|^2 = |\alpha|\langle x,x \rangle$

after which I do not know how to proceed. May I ask for some heop?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if for example $x=\alpha y$ and $\alpha\ne 0$ (if $\alpha=0$ then this immediately implies $x=0$) then:

$0=\langle x,y\rangle=\langle \alpha y, y\rangle=\alpha\langle y,y\rangle=\alpha ||y||^2$

And so $||y||=0$, which of course implies $||x||\cdot ||y||=0$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!